# Is there any way to validate counts of different object types linked by same property?

Tags: shacl

I'm trying to validate data coming from labeling documents. Each label (or code) is an anonymous node with a specific `rdf:type` (and possible other attributes, e.g. `:isPresent`, `rdfs:label`, `:comment`). `:Codes` are linked to `:Documents` via the same property (`schema:isTargetOf`).

I'd like to be able to say things like "A valid Document must have at least one code of types x, y, z, and exactly one code of type k."

```
@prefix ex: <http://example.org/ns#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix schema: <http://schema.org/> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .

ex:Document
    a schema:Document ;
    schema:isTargetOf  [ a schema:HasAuthor ;
                         schema:isPresent true ] ;
    schema:isTargetOf  [ a schema:HasImage ;
                         schema:isPresent true ] ;
    schema:isTargetOf  [ a schema:HasImage ;
                         schema:isPresent true ] ;
.
```

So, in this example a valid document must be the target of least one HasImage code and exactly one HasAuthor code.

I understand how to do it if the property is different, e.g. changing schema:isTargetOf to schema:has_author or schema:has_image.

```
ex:Document
    a schema:Document ;
    schema:has_author  [ a schema:HasAuthor ;
                         schema:isPresent true ] ;
    schema:has_image   [ a schema:HasImage ;
                         schema:isPresent true ] ;
    schema:has_image   [ a schema:HasImage ;
                         schema:isPresent true ] ;
.
```

Then I can do:

```
@prefix dash: <http://datashapes.org/dash#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix schema: <http://schema.org/> .
@prefix sh: <http://www.w3.org/ns/shacl#> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .

schema:DocumentShape
  a sh:NodeShape ;
  sh:targetClass schema:Document ;
  sh:property [
    sh:path schema:has_author ;
    sh:minCount 1 ;
    sh:maxCount 1 ;
    sh:message "Documents must have exactly 1 author"
  ] ;
  sh:property [
    sh:path schema:has_image;
    sh:minCount 1 ;
    sh:message "Must have at least one HasImage"
  ] ;
.
```

In essence I'd like to validate the collection of things linked by a single property.

Currently I'm experimenting with shacl rules to generate specific property types for each type of code, but that feels a little complicated and I wonder if there's a more direct way.

If relevant I'm using pyshacl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a use case for Qualified Value Shapes, see https://www.w3.org/TR/shacl/#QualifiedValueShapeConstraintComponent

Try some variation of

```
schema:DocumentShape
    a sh:NodeShape ;
    sh:targetClass schema:Document ;
    sh:property [
        sh:path schema:isTargetOf ;
        sh:qualifiedMinCount 1 ;
        sh:qualifiedValueShape [
            sh:class schema:HasAuthor ;
        ]
    ] ;
    sh:property [
        sh:path schema:isTargetOf ;
        sh:qualifiedMinCount 1 ;
        sh:qualifiedValueShape [
            sh:class schema:HasImage ;
        ]
    ] .
```

In the example above, isTargetOf must have at least one value of type HasAuthor, and one of type HasImage. (They might be the same value, so maybe combine it with sh:qualifiedValueShapesDisjoint and/or a sh:minCount 3 on the whole property.

Comment: Much obliged.  Not sure how I missed those, mind swimming a bit as I got that far down in the documentation :)  In addition to the examples in the spec at https://www.w3.org/TR/shacl/#QualifiedValueShapeConstraintComponent these are also discussed with examples in the Validating RDF book: https://book.validatingrdf.com/bookHtml011.html#ch050QualifiedValueShapes